# Error: No operator "=" matches these operands in "Servo_Project.cpp", Line: 15, Col: 22

Tags: embedded, stm32, mbed

So I tried using code from another post around here to see if I could use it, it was a code meant to utilize a potentiometer to move a servo motor, but when I attempted to compile it is gave the error above saying No operator "=" matches these operands in "Servo_Project.cpp". How do I go about fixing this error?

Just in case ill say this, the boards I was trying to compile the code were a NUCLEO-L476RG, the board from the post I mentioned utilized Nucleo L496ZG board and a Tower Pro Micro Servo 9G.

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "Servo.h"

Servo myservo(D6);
AnalogOut MyPot(A0);


int main() {
    float PotReading;
    PotReading = MyPot.read();

    while(1) {
     for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
            myservo = (i/100);
            wait(0.01);
        }

        }
    }
```

Comment: @Carl_Norum , okay I just tried to replace that line and compile it, but now it came up with a new error now. error 135, Class servo has no member "write"

Comment: So what does it have?

Comment: @Carl_Norum In the published library of servo it has a doc named classes, Servo.ccp, and Servo.h

Comment: servo.h has Servo(PinName Pin);, void SetPosition(int NewPos);, void Enable(int StartPos, int Period);, void Disable(); under public: under class servo{

Comment: where should write be in?

Comment: Looks like `SetPosition` is what you want, then.

Comment: So something like myservo.SetPosition(PotReading);  then?

Comment: Depends on if `PotReading` matches the scale/type expected by `SetPosition`, but that's the basic idea, yes.

Comment: Well the compiler accepts the code as valid but now whenever I put the code into the mbed the servo just doesn't move when I turn the potentiometer and i cant tell if its my wiring or my code

Comment: "_code from another post around here_" - any reason why you would not include a link to that?  Your code in the question appears to be related to https://os.mbed.com/users/simon/code/Servo/docs/tip/classServo.html, but the description of the interface in your later comment bares no resemblance to that implementation.  In other words the `Servo` class you have written code for is not the same `Servo` class you have included.  They just happen to have the same name.

Comment: Your comment regarding the content of Servo.h belongs in the question, not in the comment.  If this is third-party code, you should include a link.  You appear to be using code for a different implementation of a class called `Servo` that the one you have included.

Comment: You only read the potentiometer once outside of the servo loop, and don't even use its value to set the Servo position in any case.  However you should post a new question regarding lack of movement with the code you are actually running.  It cannot be addressed in the comments to an entirely different question.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
myservo = (i/100);
```

Is wrong in a couple of ways. First, `i/100` will always be zero - integer division truncates in C++. Second, there's not an `=` operator that allows an integer value to be assigned to a `Servo` object. YOu need to invoke some kind of `Servo` method instead, likely [`write()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ServoWrite).

```
myservo.write(SOMETHING);
```

The `SOMETHING` should be the position or speed of the servo you're trying to get working. See the [`Servo` class](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Servo) reference for an explanation. Your code tries to use fractions from 0-1 and thatvisn't going to work - the `Servo` wants a position/speed between 0 and 180.

Answer (score 0):

You should look in the Servo.h header to see what member functions and operators are implemented.

Assuming what you are using is [this](https://os.mbed.com/users/simon/code/Servo/docs/tip/classServo.html), it does have:

```
Servo& operator= (float percent);
```

Although note that the parameter is `float` and you are passing an `int`  (the parameter is also in the range 0.0 to 1.0 - so not "percent" as its name suggests - so be wary, both the documentation and the naming are poor).  You should have:

```
myservo = i/100.0f;
```

However, even though `i / 100` would produce zero for all `i` in the loop, that does not explain the error, since an implicit cast should be possible - even if clearly undesirable.  You should look in the actual header you are using to see if the `operator=` is declared - possibly you have the wrong file or a different version or just an entirely different implementation that happens to use teh same name.

I also notice that if you look in the [header](https://os.mbed.com/users/simon/code/Servo/docs/tip/Servo_8h_source.html#l00086), there is no documentation mark-up for this function and the `Servo& operator= (Servo& rhs);` member is not documented at all - hence the confusing automatically generated "*Shorthand for the write and read functions.*" on the `Servo` doc page when the function shown is only one of those things. It is possible it has been removed from your version.

Given that the documentation is incomplete and that the `operator=` looks like an after thought, the simplest solution is to use the `read()` / `write()` members directly in any case.  Or implement your own Servo class - it appears to be only a thin wrapper/facade of the [`PwmOut`](https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v5.15/apis/pwmout.html) class in any case.  Since that is actually part of mbed rather than user contributed code of unknown quality, you may be on firmer ground.